# How to get typical traffic from google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found the trafficLayer information at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer but I'm looking to include typical traffic data.  Much how google maps has their Typical Traffic popup at https://www.google.com/maps/@39.9629667,-82.9783564,12z/data=!5m1!1e1  where you can set the Day of the Week & Time.

How do I include the popup on my map & set it to a specific day/time?

EDIT:
If I can get the actual speed of the road, that would be a great bonus!

Comment: found anything related to typical traffic data ?

Answer (score 2):

Hello [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394981/matt-westlake),

Thanks for inquiring about this feature and for helping to keep this conversation alive. At the moment, the [`google.maps.TrafficLayer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#TrafficLayer) class does not support `Typical` data since the class is defaulted to `autoRefresh: true`.

You could help the community by showing support in the Google Public Issue Tracker's [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829567). Feel free to show us your support for new features and don't forget to follow our [blog](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/) for feature roll-outs, and bug fixes as [new versions of the Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#documentation-for-the-api-versions) roll-out.